# split text file in two using bash script

Tags: bash, text, sed, awk, split

I have a text file with a marker somewhere in the middle:

```
one
two
three
blah-blah *MARKER* blah-blah
four
five
six
...
```

I just need to split this file in two files, first containing everything before *MARKER*, and second one containing everything after *MARKER*. It seems it can be done in one line with awk or sed, I just can't figure out how.

I tried the easy way — using [`csplit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html), but csplit doesn't play well with Unicode text.

Answer (score 12):

you can do it easily with awk

```
awk -vRS="MARKER" '{print $0>NR".txt"}' file
```

Comment: +1: Looove it. So concise and elegant. I've been needing this to discard a large portion of garbage out of logs which came from poorly configured build script.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
awk '/MARKER/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt
```

It will read input from final.txt and produces out1.txt, out2.txt, etc...

Comment: Almost worked. Doesn't screw up UTF-8, but leaves *MARKER* in the second file.

Comment: Have you tried the solution shown here: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/41060-split-file-into-seperate-files.html - It uses `csplit` and works the way you want, that is, letting the marker out the files.

Comment: Not working as described. Needs "BEGIN{n=1}" Otherwise the initial file will be named "out.txt" and not "out1.txt". Contrary to your note. -- I tried to add this via an edit but it was rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/MARKER/q;p' inputfile > outputfile1
sed -n '/MARKER/{:a;n;p;ba}' inputfile > outputfile2
```

Or all in one:

```
sed -n -e '/MARKER/! w outputfile1' -e'/MARKER/{:a;n;w outputfile2' -e 'ba}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split` command will almost do what you want:

```
$ split -p '\*MARKER\*' splitee 
$ cat xaa
one
two
three
$ cat xab
blah-blah *MARKER* blah-blah
four
five
six
$ tail -n+2 xab
four
five
six
```

Perhaps it's close enough for your needs.

I have no idea if it does any better with Unicode than csplit, though.

Comment: That option does not seem to be available in the version of split included in GNU coreutils; I assume you're using a BSD of some flavor. In any case, on GNU-based operating systems like most Linux distros, coreutils includes both split and csplit, so they should have similar Unicode behavior.