# Delete All Text Before First Marker and After Second Marker

Tags: parsing, bash, sed, awk

So, I'm writing a script and I have a text file like this:

```
blahblahblahdeleteme
<!-- post --> 
This is the text I want to keep! Pick me!!
<!-- post navigation --> 
more text please delete me I am not needed....
```

I would like to delete the first and last parts (and the marker, if easily done) and keep the text in the middle.

Now, I know bash isn't usually the best for parsing text like this, but since it's simple I thought I might as well stick with using bash. Is this as easy as I think it should be?

I found this post: [split text file in two using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644238/split-text-file-in-two-using-bash-script)

I could split it into two text files then into two more and just keep the middle one. Is that my best bet? Please let me know!

Comment: can't you write a simple java program that uses regular expressions? If you're very specific with the markers it should be quite straightforward to write

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212799/how-do-i-extract-lines-between-two-line-delimiters-in-perl

Answer (score 6):

```
sed '1,/<!-- post -->/d;/<!-- post navigation -->/,$d' file
```

- from 1st line to first mark: delete
- from second mark to end of file ($) delete

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/<\!-- post --/,/<\!-- post navigation/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be really easy in `awk`:

```
/^<!-- post -->/ { if (start != 1)
    { start=1; firstline=1;}
}

/^<!-- post navigation -->/ {start=0;}

{ if (start == 1 && firstline != 1)
  { print $0; }
  firstline=0;
}
```